# Running Linux command as one user, but directing stdout as root

Tags: linux

I need to run the following command

```
xscreensaver -no-splash
```

as nobody, so I run

```
sudo -u nobody xscreensaver -no-splash
```

but I want to direct stdout and stderr to a file in /root

I want something like this

```
sudo (sudo -u nobody xscreensaver -no-splash) 2>&1 | tee /root/test.log
```

but that obviously doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply run `tee` also with `sudo` but as user root:

```
sudo -u nobody xscreensaver -no-splash 2>&1 | sudo tee /root/test.log
```